# How to show two Divs side by side with 100% height?

Tags: css

is there a simple css way to achieve the following layout?:

[image]

here you can see 2 div containers which are 100% in height. The right div is for menu and is 200px in width. And the left div should be also 100% in width but with a 200px margin-right (this solution is not working for me :/ ) at least not in all browsers.
If it is not possible, can anyone recommend maybe a jquery plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do like this :

**CSS**

```
.right{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}
.left{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
    height:100%;
}

html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RDyY5/

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13726054/14493760
In searching I came across this and it worked far better for me than the solution listed above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in searching for a solution to this question "How to show two Divs side by side with 100% height?" I came across the exchange linked above. The above link's solution worked much better for me and that's why i wanted to share it here.