# CSS: How to have to divs side by side with height 100%?

Tags: css, html, iframe

I am trying to create a two div's side by side that fill my screen 100%.  The left div contains some menu and the right the content.  Here's the code I have at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/HpWZW/ . The current problem is the height is only as large as my smallest div's content.  So in this case my iframe in the right column is larger than my menu items in the left column; however, the height is limited to the left divs contents not the right.  Any ideas? Thanks!

**Code**

```
<div>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="innerLeft">
            <span>Left Column</Span>
        </div>

        <div class="innerRight">
            <span>Content with Iframe</span>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>​
```

...

```
html, body {height: 100%}

.table {

    display: table;
    height: 100%;

}

.innerLeft {

    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 160px;    

    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
}

.innerRight {

    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;

    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

​

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have ran in the same problem so many times, until I found this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

It is a valid CSS solution for making your colums share the height. Then both will be the height of the largest column.

If you want to make your colums fill the whole screen you could use something like

```
.innerLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%; 
}

.innerRight {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to use absolute then fixed, otherwise the page won't scroll.

Comment: Ran into a situation... if the left columns content is larger than the screen I now have two scroll bars to the far right.  The height of the right div is only expanding to the screens resolution and not to match the left columns height

Comment: What solution are you using, the first or the last? Also you might want to remove the wrapping `.table` div.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is css3 and wont work for old browsers.

css3

```
<style>
html, body{height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
        div.table, div.table *{box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
         div.table{width:100%;height:100%;}
          div.table div{border:1px solid black;width:50%;height:100%;float:left;}
</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="innerLeft">
        <span>Left Column</Span>
    </div>

    <div class="innerRight">
        <span>Content with Iframe</span>
    </div>
</table>
```

Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height:100%;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
            div.table, div.table * {
                box-sizing:border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            }
            div.table {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            div.table div {
                border:1px solid black;
                width:50%;
                height:100%;
                float:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="innerLeft"> <span>Left Column</span>

            </div>
            <div class="innerRight"> <span>Content with Iframe</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code would create two columns whenever you would like to fill the whole screen or a section.

The following code could be used to only fill the whole screen (containers behaves odd when using position absolute, there is workarounds though):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height:100%;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
            #left {
                width:50%;
                height:100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                background:red;
            }
            #right {
                width:50%;
                height:100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                right:0;
                background:blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest answear is to use proper table, min-height can also help you, but not all browsers respect it.

Comment: I spent ages trying to work out how all the modern solutions were supposed to work and why they didn't seem to in my case. I had forgotten that a two-column, 1-row table was the "obvious" solution until I saw this post.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for what your wanting?:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sgfnm/

```
<div>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="innerLeft">
            <span>Left Column</Span>
        </div>

        <div class="innerRight">
            <span>Content with Iframe</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.table {

    display: block;

}

.innerLeft {

    display: block;
    width: 160px;    

    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
    float:left;
}

.innerRight {

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;

    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```